#  "Its" as a Possessive Pronoun

Tags: pronouns, possessives, determiners, possessive-determiners

Since *its* can be both determiner possessive pronoun and nominal possessive pronoun, an example of *its* as determiner possessive pronoun would be:

> We saved this question for last because of *its* complexity.

Because *complexity* is a noun, so *its* must be a determiner possessive pronoun in this sentence.
I'm looking for an example where *its* is used as nominal possessive pronoun in a sentence as above.

Comment: If you are looking for an example where _its_ is used as nominal possessive pronoun, I suggest the following: "The house seemed asleep yet, as I have said, it had a life of _its_ own."

Comment: Interesting question. It's tempting to say *its* can't be used as a nominal possessive pronoun (that is, like the word "hers" rather than "her"), although I might have found a published example. I'll wait for a grammarian to chime in.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: I didn't post an answer for avoiding a lot of downvotes, as it has often happened when I have cited my references. However, in this case my grammar book say: "We avoid using _its_ as possessive pronoun except when we use it with _own_."

Comment: @Carlo_R. No Carlo, you are wrong.  In “it had a life of its own”, ***its*** is not a **possessive pronoun** (substantive); it’s a **possessive determiner** (adjective), which is precisely the distinction the OP was asking about. You have misunderstood the question. These are more distinct in English, Spanish, or French than they are in Italian; this may be your error.  Contrast EN *my, your* / ES *mi, tu* / FR *mon, ton* with EN *mine, yours* / ES *el mío, tuyo* / FR *le mien, tien*, but Italian has only *il mio, tuo* or sometimes just *mio, tuo*, which are not so different as in the others.

Comment: @AndrewLeach See my answer for an OED citation from Shakespeare. John also provides examples of *its* as a true possessive pronoun.

Comment: @tchrist: Could also be called a "possessive pro-determiner" if that aspect is important.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It’s much more common to use *its* as a ***possessive determiner***  like *my*, *her*, or *their*, than it is to use it as a ***possessive pronoun*** like *mine*, *hers*, or *theirs*.

A possessive determiner goes in the determiner slot of a larger noun phrase; there still has to be a noun later on in that noun phrase.

In contrast, a possessive pronoun is an actual substantive all by itself and so needs no noun following.

Using *its* in this way is possible but not common.  The ᴏᴇᴅ2 calls this an absolute possessive, used when no substantive follows.  They provide just one citation, from Shakespeare’s *Henry VIII*. Here’s the full extended quote:

> Then you lost
>   The view of earthly glory: men might say,
>   Till this time pomp was single, but now married
>   To one above itself. Each following day
>   Became the next day’s master, till the last
>   Made former wonders ***its***.

As a possessive pronoun instead of a possessive determiner, *its* means “its ones”, and is marked “rare” in the ᴏᴇᴅ.

---

Here are some other examples taken from Google Books:

- I was still shaking, so I couldn't tell if the vibrations the body made were **its** or mine.
- The Church had different interests from powerful freemen, whose lands were subject to confiscation in a way that **its** were not, and rarely made ...
- But still my eyes with maddening gaze 
   Were fixed upon its fearful face, 
   And **its** were fixed on me.
- It was the tongue that their mothers taught them to speak, **its** were the words used in courtship by young men and maidens, and its accents were the last heard from relatives and friends
- As far as lifespans go, **its** had been a relatively long one but that had now ended.
- Group work is neither mine nor yours nor ours nor **its**.
- I then briefly consider the state’s agenda in its own terms, or at least in terms (probably somewhere between **its** and ours) external to Sherpa society.
- Multiply the amount of each bill by the time between **its** and the first purchase...
- Look for vulnerabilities—**its** and ours.
- Perhaps the freedom of another cannot belong to me, cannot be given by the essence of my subjectivity, cannot belong to any essence, even that of subjectivity, **its** or mine.
- But it would doubtless be more accurate to affirm that **its** and ours are in keeping.
- A fall 2008 tour brought fans closer to 1950s Jughead long before Juliet whacks it to death (both **its** and hers).
- Thereupon, the rabbit replied that the mistake was neither **its**, nor of the other animals.
- ...with the result that we never know whether the forces that bear us are its or ours—...
- Yesterday, yet another happily newlywed couple'd taken a look at the place, open and shut cabinets, tested the blinds, **its** and hers and theirs; elbowed one another as they smirked at the beds...

Comment: The reference I found is [by Nancy Fraser](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EcgSDuc2bWQC&lpg=PA390&ots=4ZPiM4LGNp&pg=PA390#v=onepage&q&f=false) -- "Her subject, like its, is split into two halves..."

Comment: Anything goes in poetry. Having 'its' stand alone doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yup, that’s definitely a real possessive pronoun not just a possessive adjective. May I ask how you found it? These are quite challenging to google for without being flooded with false positives for the determiner usage.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Nice detective work!

Comment: @Mitch I trust you meant to write *common* there, not *right*.  It certainly doesn’t sound wrong. You just don’t hear it much, perhaps because as John says, possession is seldom attributed to inanimate antecedents.

Comment: I looked for "Its is" and went through several pages of results about Intelligent Transport Systems.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I agree with Cameron: nice detective work! I was trying for “its are” and getting nowhere. Another “its is” is: “This method of modern psychology, for its is very modern as well as very ancient, serves as the basis for the communication...” by Michael Bertiaux. I bet use of bare *its* as an object of preposition would be more common than in subject position, but these too are devilishly tough to search for.

Comment: @tchrist: no, I didn't mean 'common' at all. None of the examples mentioned so far sound right. Please give more examples; maybe then I could tell. John's example -might- work, but I really expect 'its' to modify something, not stand by itself.

Comment: @Mitch I’ve given many more examples now.

Comment: @tchrist: Wow, impressive footwork!

Comment: @tchrist: OK, OK, I get it. Those sound acceptable, but I agree with the OED that it is rare sounding. But the Shakespeare usage sounds really bad (yes, I know this seems pretty presumptuous, but I'm just talking about modern standard English).

Comment: @Mitch Shakespeare often sounds a bit off to the modern ear.  I think you’ve been garden-pathed to think that in that particular example, *its* would normally require a noun following it, making it a determiner/adjective instead of the much rarer pronoun/substantive. I mean in a way that doesn’t happen with my more recent examples, where there are various syntactic cues to disambiguate usage (and in fact, these are what I searched on) that do not occur in the Shakespeare quote.

Comment: @tchrist, not a bad answer. Your examples are somewhat interesting - we need more info: author? type of publication/register? year? dialect? etc.

Comment: I have to admit that to me, every single one of these examples of _its_ as a pronoun is quite simply ungrammatical. Not just jarring or awkward, but ungrammatical. The only exception is when other possessive pronouns are listed alongside it: “both mine and yours and its” is at least _marginally_ grammatical to me, though still clumsy and awkward. I wonder if this is purely a dialect/idiolect thing, or if the grammaticality of pronominal _its_ is generally in the process of decreasing and disappearing.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’ve been thinking and thinking about your comment here. On the one hand, the Google Books citations show **some** writers do find it grammatical. On the other, you do not—and perhaps even more interestingly, neither does Mitch, who has probably been speaking English longer than you and I put together. The OED calls this pronominal use “rare”, and there must be some reason for that rarity; maybe “sounds wrong” is why. The citations were hard for me to come up with, which I am wondering whether to attribute not only to my poor Google-fu but also to actual corporal infrequency.

Answer (score 27):

That shell is not mine. Nor is it yours. It belongs to that snail over there.

> *That shell is its, not mine or yours.*

As you can see, this construction doesn't occur often, because possession is not often attributed to neuter nouns, [let alone](https://user.phil-fak.uni-duesseldorf.de/~filip/fillmore+88.pdf) pronouns.

Comment: Indeed, the OED even goes so far as to call this “rare”, not just uncommon.

Comment: No. The shell is **mine**!

Comment: No. It's its. :)

Answer (score 10):

I spent quite a while hunting around online for examples that struck me as plausible.  The only ones I find acceptable have a country, government, or similar organization as the antecedent of *its*, along the following lines:

1. After the attack, Germany accounted for all of its delegates satisfactorily, but France said that two of its were missing.
2. With regard to policy changes, the government denied that any of its constituted u-turns.

Note that there is an issue of grammatical terminology here, though.  These examples involve ellipsis after *its* (*its [delegates]*, *its [changes]*).  So, you might count these as instances of as determiners.

To avoid these problems, you could adapt John Lawler’s example (which really jars for me, to the extent that I’m not sure it’s grammatical for me at all; possibly a dialect difference?) to have, again, a country as the antecedent.  But I’m still far from enamoured with the result:

1. Despite Argentine belligerence, the United Kingdom asserts that the Falkland Islands are its, and that Argentine claims to the contrary are ...
2. Spain recently attempted to raise the issue, but the United Kingdom still regards Gibraltar as its, irrevocably.

Comment: All seem to satisfy the requirement, but I wonder if *hers, theirs, hers* and *hers* (respectively) would be more normally used?

Comment: I believe that, in your final example, it should be Gibraltar rather than Grenada :)

Comment: @AndrewLeach.  In a formal context, yes, _hers_, _etc._ would be more common.  But using _her_ for countries feels like an affectation for me, even though I’m fully aware that it’s absolutely standard for many other speakers.  Maybe something to do with my generation (of Australians?)?  I’d be curious to hear whether other speakers also feel that these forms are not quite native for them.

Comment: Good call, Daniel, on looking for “its were”, as this proves more profitable than “its are” or “its is” queries in terms of lower false positives. Ex: “In fact, unless required to work together in a particular training exercise, each force carried on its daily activity as if its were the SAF alone,...” Calvin Allen & Lynn Rigsbee. “The most important of its were firstly, the relaxation of governmental control over the local authorities in regard to the preparation and approval of budgets..” K.R. Gupta. “...would give an idea of return to nature, as its were.” Mandal. Plus many more like that.

Answer (score 6):

I admire the work done by those who have dug up such an incredible amount of examples in which *"**its**"* is used as a possessive pronoun.

However, as I'm not a native speaker of English, I normally go by the teachings of grammar books, so I looked up Swan's "*Practical English Usage - Third Edition*" which states :

> ***Its*** is not normally used without a following noun.
>
> I've had my breakfast, and the dog's had **its breakfast** too.* [NOT ... *and the dog's had its*.] 1

Another frequently used grammar textbook for EFL teaching is Murphy's "*English Grammar in Use*". On this subject the author does not go so far as to say that "*its*" is not used, still he does not list it along with possessive pronouns, which in my opinion is meaningful. 2

There are other grammars which share this position, on top of the indication to be found in OED, so I think it should be safe to conclude that, although the usage of *"**its**"* as a possessive pronoun is sometimes found in texts, still it is rather rare. And I would go so far as to recommend foreigners like myself to avoid using it whenever possible.

1  M. Swan "Practical English Usage" - paragraph 442 - possessives (4) pages 417-18

2  R. Murphy "English Grammar in Use" 2nd edition - Unit 81A page 162

(another reference  could be Michael Vince's "*Micmillan English Grammar in Context*" which, when listing possessive pronouns, leaves a blank where ***its*** should be found.)

Comment: Sorry, I can’t agree with this. If you’re so keen on “grammars”, then let it be noted that Greenbaum’s *Oxford English Grammar* disagrees with you, where in section **3.26.C: Possessive pronouns** on page 85 he specifically includes ***its*** when enumerating the 3rd-person possessive pronouns of English. He does add that “The independent function is rare for *its*.”, which he has previously defined as the standalone version that doesn’t take a noun afterwards. There’s really nothing confusing about saying “Mine are ready, but ***its*** are not.” It’s really works just like ***theirs***.

Comment: @tchrist. As I said at first, I appreciate all the information and the examples which have been listed about the possibility to use ***its*** as a possessive pronoun. At the same time, not having the support of mother-tongue knowledge, I have to rely on grammars. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the one you mention, but what it states is not very different from my conclusion, that is that *"its"* is rare, and I personally feel it is safer for me not to use it, in order to avoid mistakes. I never said that using it creates confusion.

Comment: +1 Paola. For adding another reference: "We avoid using its as possessive pronoun except when we use it with _own_." English Grammar Today (Cambridge) says. On this _its_ usage (possessive pronoun), in this book is reported the following example: "The house seemed asleep yet, as I have said, it had a life of its own." However a competent  user said that this example is wrong.

Comment: @tchrist, What exactly do you disagree with? "*Its* is not normally used without a following noun" (Swan, see above), "recommend foreigners to avoid using it whenever possible", or "sometimes found in texts, still it is rather rare."

Comment: @Carlo_R. You are mistaken. "She had a life of **her** own". NOT She had a life of *hers own or "She had a life of *hers." However you could say: "She had her own life, it was **hers** and nobody else's." AND *possibly*: Although asleep the house seemed to possess a life of its own, not of its owners but of **its**."

Comment: @Mari-L, yes, I know, this is an extremely difficult matter in comparison with the knowledge of the English language I have, but, surely, when I posted the above comment I was unware that the grammar book I cited was wrong, and, consequently, today I don't use it anymore, even if, however, I don't have another to use.

Comment: Those who said "its own" may not be wrong. Let's not forget that "its" can both be possessive pronoun and possessive adjective... The seven possessive pronouns are MINE, YOURS, THEIRS, OURS, HERS, HIS, and ITS. Their adjectival counterparts are MY, YOUR, THEIR, OUR, HER, HIS and ITS. Note that HIS and ITS retain the same spelling both as a pronoun and as an adjective. Therefore, if one can say HER OWN, one can  equally say ITS own, and if one can say THE BOOK IS HERS, one can equally say THE KENNEL IS ITS.   "I've had my breakfast and the dog's had ITS own ( its here is a possessive adjective)

Comment: What's this one the table?... It's the dog's food...the food (on the table) is its...("its " here is a possessive pronoun). In conclusion, the word "own" in the dog has had its own appears to be a pronoun replacing the noun food, so the "its" before it is certainly an adjective, not a pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

To complement and update tchrist's excellent answer: the new on-line version of the OED has 6 examples of "its" as a possessive pronoun:

> 1623   Shakespeare & J. Fletcher Henry VIII i. i. 18   Each following
>   day Became the next dayes master, till the last Made former Wonders,
>   it's.
>
> 1835   W. Scott Infantry Tactics II. 51   The second division has
>   already taken its position in the column, the third has nearly taken
>   its.
>
> 1864   M. V. Victor in W. T. Coggeshall Poets & Poetry of West 521/2
>   'Twas of royal rank, for all the past Was its by right of birth.
>
> 1920   E. F. Corbett Puritan & Pagan xxiv. 294   The crowd which was
>   hers, and she its.
>
> 1932   ‘L. G. Gibbon’ Sunset Song i. 45   There are better things than
>   your books or studies or loving or bedding, there's the countryside
>   your own, you its, in the days when you're neither bairn nor woman.
>
> 2004   I. M. Banks Algebraist (2005) i. 8   Claiming the vengeance
>   that was so surely its, exacting the price its enemies all deserved to
>   pay.