# What's this? What is it? but not What's it? - Why?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, pronunciation

Can anyone give a cogent, simply described explanation of why the verb *BE* in:

- What is it?

... doesn't seem to be able to be contracted with the subject:

- What's it? *

Compare the sentences above with:

- What's this?
- What's that?

These are perfectly fine. In fact, the contractions here should be expected in almost all examples of spoken English.

Answers with references to authoritative vetted sources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Though the question is entirely different, I would say that [this answer of mine](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/126839/47827) also adequately answers this question—assuming you accept that _it_ in this function is inherently unstressed and cannot populate the mandatory predicate stress slot (unlike _this_, and also _it_ in some other cases, like “That’s it!” or even “What’s ‘it’?”).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well that's what I thought (kind of) on first consideration. Then I realised that *What* is the object here, therefore part of the predicate. When first considering *What is it?* I decided that the *is* is stranded because its complement has been fronted, so therefore *is* must be a strong form. However, consideration of *What's that?* seems to shoot that to pieces. The only difference I can perceive is that *that*, being deictic, is stressed, whereas *it* will usually be de-accented, because it's virtually always old information. Don't know if this would matter...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Very, very nice post btw!

Comment: I don't think the rules that govern sentential stress slots really care whether _what_ is subject or predicate on a deeper syntactic level—there's simply a ‘subject slot’ and a ‘predicate slot’, and the cutoff point between them is the verb (which is included in the latter).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet (Must remember which comment I'm on!)... I don't quite understand why according to that answer *is* wouldn't need to be strong in *What's that?* but would need to be in *What is it?*. I'm not sure, but it also seems to me that if we have *what* as part of the predicate, and obligatorily stressed, then *is* shouldn't need to be stressed according to the theory as described?

Comment: I would say that _what_ fills the ‘subject slot’ (SS) and _is it/that_ the ‘predicate slot’ (PS). If we accept that this usage of _it_ is mandatorily unstressed, then the stress in the PS must fall on the verb, ’cause there's nowhere else for it to go. _That_, on the other hand, is mandatorily stressed and can carry the PS stress, which means the verb doesn't have to and becomes a candidate for contraction.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, this is what got me onto asking the question in the first place. That's what I originally proposed to my fellow grammar anaorak - colleague. Problem is *that* isn't in the predicate!!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... because *that* is the subject and *what* is the complement ... (which is why I had to backtrack and then put this question up on here because my head hurt ...)

Comment: Like I said higher up, and the reason I'm using quotes around the terms, I don't see these slots as being equivalent to syntactical entities. They're prosodic entities and don't necessarily have to correspond to syntactical entities. The default sentence type is SVO (=SP), and that's what the slots are based on. In cases like these, where you basically have OVS (or CVS), the stress slots still pivot around the verb in the same way. Wackernagel trumps syntax when stressing sentences, I think.

Comment: Note that taking the verb as the pivot (and perhaps speaking of a pre-verbal slot PVS and a verb-complex slot VCS instead) also accounts for cases with fronted complements or objects: “Boring he is, but clever he's not”—the PVS here includes both the subject complement and the subject, whereas the VCS simply starts at the verb and covers everything that comes after, so the first sentence can't be contracted, but the second can.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Do the same test trying to contract a three syllable sentence beginning with *Who is* into *Who’s*, and you find something interesting. Normally *Who’s it?* is blocked, although *Who’s it for?* is not because the sentence now ends with a stressed word. However, if you are playing “Tag! You’re It!” then suddenly it’s allowed, since *it* has become a noun more than a pronoun, and so becomes stressed and valid. You can say “Who’s it?” in that context. Because possessive pronouns are stressed but but not possessive determiners, some resist ending the sentence with the p.p. *its*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet See also [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/76339) about the resistance that some native speakers have against using *its* at the end a sentence **even when this *its*** is a stressed possessive pronoun like *mine* instead of as the unstressed possessive determiner like *my*. In sentence-final position, even normally unstressed purely function words  like *is, has, are, have, can, with, in, and* gain stress there — and when they do, now you are allowed to contract words like *is* or *has* that came right before them, when normally you could not.

Comment: _It_'s not contracted because it's final; final _be_ doesn't contract: **I said that it isn't but he said that it's*. _This_ and _that_ are stressed after _is_, but _it_ normally isn't, so that makes it sound weird uncontracted, too.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think there might be something in your comment, but there seems to be a hole in it, to me at least. You can strand *BE* in other situations but have following stressed words, but this doesn't seem to allow the cliticisation of *BE*. For example: A: "Is it open?" B:"I think it is *sometimes*". Now that answer from B can't be "I think it's sometimes".

Comment: It's right before a deletion site, though. _Open_ has been deleted by conjunction reduction, and I think the same rule applies -- probly I shoulda stated it as forbidding contraction before a deletion site, but it's fairly far out of my area.

Comment: In Araucaria's example "I think it is sometimes", the "sometimes" is a sentence modifier that is not part of the verb phrase "it is".  The last thing in the verb phrase has to be stressed. On the other hand, the "sometimes" is in the verb phrase when it is positioned between the verb and an element of the verb phrase, as in "I think it is sometimes open".  That's why the former "is" cannot be contracted, but the latter one can be.

Comment: To answer, the reason why you think "it doesn't seem to be able to be contracted" seems pertinent. My guess is that your answer will be something along the line of "it doesn't sound right", in which case your question posits that a matter of opinion can be resolved by a matter of fact...which may be true, but if so, the mechanism whereby it is true is unknowable.

Comment: @tchrist, Re your first comment, in the last sentence did you mean "resist ending the sentence with the **p.d.** *its*"? Since you said possessive pronouns are stressed but possessive determiners aren't, shouldn't ending a sentence with the p.d. *its* be found more unacceptable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(1) The word "it" doesn't like to be stressed. (2) Normally, a sentence has its strongest stress on the last thing that can be stressed, which in a simple subject-verb-object sentence will the object, since that is the last thing.

Principles (1) and (2) interact to give the strongest stress on the verb of a sentence, in case the object is "it" -- since the stress can't go on the "it", the last eligible thing for stress is the verb.  Compare "I like **yoghurt**" with "I **like** it".

(3) Stressed vowels cannot be deleted.

Putting together (1-3), we deduce that the "is" in "What **is** it?" will be stressed, and consequently cannot be contracted to *"What's it?", because that would require deleting the "i" of "is", which must be stressed because of the following "it".

Comment: How do you account for the contractability of "Who's it?" (commonly encountered, for example, in the game of tag)?

Comment: The rule that "it" is not stressed concerns the pronoun "it".  The "it" in the game of "it" is not a pronoun, so it gets stress, and consequently preceding "is" can be contracted.

Comment: So, asking "Who's it?" about someone at the door doesn't work. Reminds me of a knock-knock joke, but I take your point. The OP is asking for "authoritative vetted sources". Do you have any such that, particularly, make the distinction between between pronominal 'it' and nominal 'it'? I ask because your answer specifies "the word", not the pronoun.

Comment: My account of the stress is a simplification of the treatment in **SPE**, where the nuclear stress rule formalizes the tendency in English for the main stress of a phrase to come at the end.  Also, Chomsky and Halle note that pronouns don't take stress.  I don't think they draw the obvious implication about contraction, but of course you can't stress a vowel that isn't there.  (I was thinking of myself as a vetted source.)

Comment: I accept your self-vetting, but I suspect the OP is thinking more along the lines of peer-reviewed--despite the strong evidence, if not proof, that being 'peer-reviewed' is no more likely an indicator of underlying expertise than, for example, the acquisition of 'reputation' here by reason of longevity, prolificity, and popularity.

Comment: @JEL "*How do you account for the contractability of "Who's it?"*" <---- That's a no brainer. The word *it* there is a proper noun, not a pronoun.

Comment: @Araucaria, I guess...not when we played, and not like Cousin It, but okay, different linguistic cultures I suppose. The name of the game was "Tag" for us. Maybe I misunderstood at the time. Anyway, Mr. Lee said quite clearly "the *word* it", not "the *pronoun* it"; but again, now that it's been made clear, I guess such imprecision is acceptable in this domain (where duplicates are not duplicates, obsolete is not obsolete, etc.), however questionable it may've been to start. That leaves the "doesn't seem to be able to be contracted" of your question a matter of opinion. Shibboleth?

Comment: @JEL, Araucaria, When I wrote my answer, it just didn't occur to me that I should formulate it with "the pronoun 'it'".  I noticed after JEL brought it up.

Comment: My answer referred to the word "it".  "It" is not "this".  So why shouldn't "this" be stressed?  In fact, it is stressed.  "This" is not even a pronoun.  You seem to be imagining generalizations or alternatives to my answer, then criticizing those.  So "is" is not a content word -- what does that have to do with what I said?  What is this "stranding"?

Comment: @GregLee I'm not criticising your answer! I'm just still ruminating over the difference between that sentence and the other two examples in the question - which is where my original confusion, interest in the question stems from. So my purpose of speaking to you here is just to pick your brains and converse with you.  Stranding just means that the complement of the auxiliary has been deleted or moved to a different site. Here, it seems to me, the complement of *BE* is probably the word *What*. The only thing that I don't understand in relation to your answer is that if some particular ....

Comment: @GregLee ... word becomes destressed we'd normally expect the nucleus to move to the previous content word, wouldn't we? So in your *like* example, I'd expect *like* to take the nucleus because it's a content words and  *it*, as you say doesn't take stress, and in any case represents old information in the conversation. Maybe it would be better if I gave a genuine example that seems to buck your explanation (I'll delete most of the comments above and then these ones after you've read them. (PS, I won't get pinged if you don't address any comments to me!)

Comment: @GregLee So how about the following conversation (all *that*s and *this*es are incidental in this  btw): A: "That's not the one we've been looking for, it's *that* one with the blue top." B: "Oh, *that*'s it! I thought it was the other one!" C: "*What's* it? I can't see anything". In that conversation, *it* is also the last word, but *BE* doesn't seem to become stressed. And B's comment would work, imo, if they said "Oh, *that* is it! ..." with the *BE* uncontracted. Those examples don't surprise me because I wouldn't expect *BE* to take stress normally, because it's a function word ...

Comment: @GregLee And then there's C's response too. It seems to me that *is* isn't stranded in C's answer which is why it can be weak - and that stranding ***in conjunction with your 1-3*** might explain why *is* is stressed in the OQ. But I don't know I'm just bandying around an idea. I hadn't got anywhere till I'd read your answer!

Comment: @GregLee ***But*** ... if the fact that the Complement's been fronted means that *is* must be stressed, then the other two examples given for comparison in my question seem to pose a problem ... namely why is *is* cliticizable there? [and the reason I'm asking *you* under your post is because I suspect you're the only person who might be able to help! - not because I'm trying to criticise your excellent answer]

Comment: On your example conversation with A, B, C sentences, I agree that the last "it" would be stressed.  I attribute that to its metalinguistic sense -- it's part of a comment about the language that was used in the earlier part of the conversation, as opposed to the ideas expressed.  The convention is to use scare quotes here.  What is this "it" that you refer to?

Comment: Broadly speaking, in describing the stress, you are appealing to two ideas that are entirely absent from the SPE analysis, and from mine.  One is the notion that stress depends on syntactic derivation (this was part of Joan Bresnan's analysis), and the other is that it has something to do with information structure -- old/new, topic/comment, or whatever.  It's a good thing to pursue other ideas, but you ought to know when you're headed off in a different direction.  In the SPE analysis, the stress contour depends only on the surface phonological and syntactic structure.

Comment: @GregLee I guess a lot of that's also because I was trained by phoneticians and not phonologists. I'm more from a Wells background, less from a generative one ...

Comment: Phoneticians taught you to appeal to derivations?  I didn't think phoneticians even knew about derivations, or if they did, certainly didn't believe in them.

Comment: Isn't saying "Who's it" wrong unless it's followed by something else, such as "Who's it concerning"? I've never heard anyone say "Who's it?" in place of "Who is it?"

Comment: Do you know of any good references to learn more about this topic? I'd like to know more about it, but I'm very new to this.

Comment: @MrReality, Other than what I said in previous comments, I don't know of other good references.

Comment: @GregLee, is the rule that "Normally, a sentence has its strongest stress on the last thing that can be stressed", true if the object has an article? And if it is a proper noun? ...

Comment: ... Also, re your reply to JEL, can you elaborate on why the "it" in "Who's it" in the game of tag isn't a pronoun? Does it lose any properties of a pronoun and/or gain some properties of a noun?

Comment: @MrReality Because it refers to a role in a game rather than a preceding noun phrase in the conversation.

Comment: @GregLee, what about the comment previous to that? Do you know whether the  stress rule you mentioned normally also applies to the objects having an article, or that are proper nouns?

Comment: @MrReality Yes, it does, with the qualification that later mentions of the same phrase have low stress (as do pronouns),

Answer (score 9):

It's a perfectly grammatical contraction, though it doesn't commonly stand alone; it's usually followed by another word.

> - *What's it* all about, Alfie?
> - *What's It*? - The Award Winning Game Where Creative Minds Think Alike!
> - Sun, sea and silver service: *what’s it* like crewing on a superyacht?
> - *What's It*? - Information Today
> - *What's It* Like on the Pope's Plane?
> - *What's it* to you, anyway?
> - *What's it do?"

The problem with your example is that in the short, stand alone phrase "What is it?" (just as with *Who is it?*), the emphasis is on *is*, not *what*. If there is no emphasis on *is*, then the phrase is simply *What?* If the emphasis is on *it*, then something for the dummy-it must be stated, as in the cases above, or, *What's it like outside?* (*Who's it gonna be?*)

**edited to add:** Please see @John Lawler's comment.

Comment: It's certainly helpful! :) One of my problems is that the necessary strong - ie not-contracted - form of *is* is the exceptional bit. As you show, when there are following complements or adjuncts, *BE*, of course, is always contractible. I'm not sure about the *Information Today* title, not because it's not a proper title, but because I'm not sure that *What's it* can be used in real speech as a question in so-called "standard English". Also why obligatory emphasis on *is* in *what is it?*, but not in *What's that?*

Comment: I think this answers something that is slightly, but crucially, different from the question. When you add more elements to the sentence, you change the basis for stress assignment and thereby also contraction, so though there are many instances of “what’s it […]”, those all end up being incomparable to the ‘simplex’ sentence “*What’s it?”. Now the game show and the Information Today titles, those are very interesting, because they actually do use something that isn't valid as a natural sentence.

Comment: +1 for your previous answer ( no less for this one). But I don't think I follow with the theory that if there's no emphasis on *is* the phrase is simply *What?* If someone gives you a strange object why do you need to stress *is* in *What is it?*, but you don't in *What's that?*. The reasons for stressing *is* in both examples seem to be the same. *What?* on it's own doesn't seem to be an adequate response in this situation - imo. What do you think?

Comment: It also reminds me that nouns derived from similar phrases seemingly always have contracted forms: _whatsit_, _whatchamacallit_, etc. Most of them have additional elements, so contractions aren't that odd, but _whatsit_ doesn't. You'd really expect that to be called a _whaddisit_ or something.

Comment: How quickly we forget the childhood game of Tag!  *Tag, you’re it!  Who’s it?  I’m it!*

Comment: @tchrist Very true. As you say above, it's more like *Who's It?* in that example, so there does seem to be something requiring a stressed word after the contraction even if it's not a complement ...

Comment: @Araucaria - Agree with the above; tchrist nailed the perfect example. You asked a very interesting question. Haven't been overwhelmed with those recently. It's been an interesting discussion!

Comment: _What's it do?_ is **not** ungrammatical; it's the contraction for _What does it do?_ The -'s (really a /z/, but devoiced to /s/ after /t/ from _What_) can stand for _is_ or _does_ (though not _was_, the same way -'d can stand for _could_ or _did_); _What's he do?_ is short for _What does he do?_

Comment: @JohnLawler - please forgive me, that answer was written a long time ago. You're correct, of course. I'll edit.

Answer (score 3):

> What is it?
> What's this?
> What's that?

Why are people so averse to providing context? English lives and breathes through context.

The proper way to approach this is to ask how the expressions are used, not to examine them as isolated phrases that can be poked at and dissected without any reference to real-life usage.

> **Example**
>
> (a) Jane points at an object lying on the table. She says, "What's
> **that**?"
>
> The word 'that' is strongly stressed. We understand that something new
> has come to Jane's attention. The something is **that**.  The verb 'is' cannot take a position of stress because that is already occupied.
>
> (b) Jane points at an object lying on the table. She says
>
> "What **is** that?"
>
> This time, the word 'is' is strongly stressed. Jane is talking about something that is already under scrutiny by those present but
> now she is saying, "I see it but now I want to know what it **is**"  Clearly we can't abbreviate 'is' in this case.

Now all we have to do is apply the same reasoning to 'it'.

(c) Someone hands an object to Jane, she enquires, "What **is** it?" This is similar to case (b). There is a known object and Jane wants some information about it.

(d) Now we come to the 'impossible' case. There is an object.

Jane says, "What's **it?**"

This should be like case (a). That is to say, the object is new to Jane. However  a vital property of the word 'it' is that it must have an antecedent. Therefore Jane must already have mentioned it. So it can't be like case (a). This case doesn't happen because there can never be a context that warrants it.

**Conclusion**

You can only understand the reason by considering the contexts in which the expressions can be used. You cannot do it by simply reasoning about the isolated phrase—English requires context.

Unlike for 'this' and 'that', there is simply no context that allows emphasis on the word 'it'.

Comment: It is not actually a "vital property" of the word "it" that it have an antecedent.  For instance, the "it" at the beginning of the sentence preceding this one.  For another example, take "It's raining".

Comment: @GregLee - That's a very good observation. In fact, it blows the whole thing apart. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Jane's "What's it?" is a nominal (or noumenal, you choose) use of 'it' with reference to the 'it' in John's "It's raining". Try this: "At the other end, the phone rang three times, and then a woman's voice said "Yeah, what's it?".

Comment: @JEL - Good points.  With regard to the phone scenario - there's a deletion. The woman is effectively saying, "You rang me about something. What **is** it?"

Comment: @JEL - You're right about the nominal. I'm going to have to revert to my older answer. The impersonal 'it' in expressions like 'It's raining', is being used in a different way to the normal 'it' that requires an antecedent. Suppose you'd never seen rain before: You would not point at rain and say "What's **it**?" because the idiom in English is to point and say, "What's **that**?"  If we didn't have demonstrative pronouns in English then maybe we *would* say, "What's **it**?"

Comment: Having taken note of comments, I think I need to do a rewrite. I'm still happy with my answer but I need to sharpen it up. In a while I'll delete this version and submit a clearer version.

Comment: A: It shows that dogs are more intelligent that cats?

Comment: B: Does it now?  What’s **it**?

Comment: So is "Where's that?" correct?