# Can dummy "it" occur as possessive "its"?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, dummy-it, possessive-pronouns

I don't want to get too bogged down in exactly what constitutes a dummy pronoun usage (personally, I'd include things like *Who's there? **It's** John*, even if not everyone else does).

But on [this recent ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105993/) I wrote the comment [I'm not convinced the possessive form **its** can ever be a true "dummy" usage.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105993/can-it-be-used-to-refer-to-a-person/105998?noredirect=1#comment211048_105998)

The only reason I said I'm "not convinced" is because I couldn't think of any examples. Can anyone either prove me wrong or explain why I'm right?

Comment: I can't find any evidence either: http://awelu.srv.lu.se/grammar-and-words/selective-mini-grammar/pronouns/dummy-pronouns/

Comment: As far as I know (though I’ll admit I have no sources for the claim), dummy _it_ can only function as the subject of a clause. That is, the _full_ subject. Since _its_ can only ever be a determiner, it can never function as the full subject of a clause. I’d say the two are mutually exclusive and there is no possibility of a dummy _it_.

Comment: @Janus: That makes a lot of sense. Without wishing to get too precise about exactly how one defines "dummy pronoun", I suppose it's reasonable to say the usage only arises in the first place *because the **syntactic** context requires a **subject*** (where ***semantically*** we're unwilling or unable to explicitly identify that subject).

Comment: 'It's doing its best to rain.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nice! But doesn't 'its' refer to (the first) 'It' (the dummy)?

Comment: Some would distinguish 'dummy it' from 'weather it' anyway; these are both weather it. The unarguable dummy usage ('It's a long way to Tipperary') is a fronting device; a possessive doesn't come into the picture. Think of the French equivalent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I mean that if one says "Rambo is shooting. He's doing his best." then the 'his' refers to 'He', not (directly) to 'Rambo'. Right? Wrong?

Comment: Surely referentiality here is a transitivity (maths sense) property: _his_ refers to _He_ refers to _Rambo_.  If I say 'It's cold and it's miserable', I wouldn't start analysing whether the second 'it' had an antecedent – they're both just function words. A dummy is only there as a place-holding substitutionary device. With my tongue-in-cheek example, I'd guess that the people who started using the double-it format realised that they were being rather non-standard. 'It's cold and it needs to do something about its coldness' would be extremely non-standard / quirky.

Comment: When people say 'surely' that usually means that it is not _quite_ true (or simply false). :) In this case I think that 'his' refers to 'He'. Full stop. As, _surely_, grammar does not extend to _multiple_ sentences.

Comment: [*I am not sure what to do, even as I am writing this post **it's** taking **its** time for the letters to appear on the screen.*](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7193593?start=0&tstart=0) I suppose both "it"'s there must refer to the same thing, but is that definitely "this post", or is it just a dummy?

Comment: I would think that 'its' refers to "it'. Even if 'it' were a dummy, then 'its' still isn't, despite (or: because of) 'it' being a dummy.

Comment: @Keep these mind: Well, there does seem to be a difference between my example and Edwin's - syntactically, his construction *requires* the second (possessive) pronoun, whereas mine *doesn't*. In which context it seems to me that if we *do* remove ***its*** from my version, it's much harder to justify the idea that the "it" of ***it's** taking time for the letters to appear* actually refers to "this post".

Answer (score 7):

As I'm sure you know, one of English's "small clause" constructions consists of a subject and a gerund phrase, where the subject may be either in the objective/accusative case ("them leaving was a surprise") or the possessive/genitive case ("their leaving was a surprise").

This is the case even when the subject is a dummy *it*. Hence, we find the following (real) examples:

> - […] the reader is conscious of **its** being John the Baptist who speaks these words: […] [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=ooPmuU1ibBwC&pg=PT78&dq=its)]
> - […] the possibility of **its** raining […] [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=BZpFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA203&dq=its)]
> - […] most philosophers are committed to **its** being impossible that 1 + 1 = 3 […] [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=cPJZCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA116&dq=its)]

though in all three cases, *it* could have been used instead (at the risk of irritating prescriptivists).

---

That said, I *don't* think this use of dummy *its* is ever possible with nouns as opposed to gerunds; for example, although "them/their leaving was a surprise" can be reworded as "their departure was a surprise", "its raining was a surprise" obviously can't be reworded as *"its rain was a surprise".

Consequently, I also don't think that the *non*-subject uses of dummy *it* have corresponding uses of dummy *its*. English does have an "objective genitive" — consider e.g. "her nomination", meaning "her being nominated" — but it's comparatively restricted, and I don't think it ever works with gerunds, only with nouns. (The nouns can be identical to gerunds, as in e.g. "his killing at the hands of […]", but I think they do have to be nouns: cf. "a series of killings".)

Comment: Excellent thinking! Hadn’t thought of this possibility at all. Those examples pretty much have to be considered dummy _its_’es (unless you count weather _it_ as a separate thing, in which case the second one isn’t). They all sound quite bizarre to me (I would perforce use _it_, prescriptivists be damned), but I can’t deny that they’re structurally sound and that the only possible reason they could be ungrammatical is that they’re possessive dummy _it_’s.

Comment: What @Janus said. I must admit that if *the possibility of **its** being used like this* had occurred to me when I was posing the question here, I'd probably have just dismissed it (thinking "That doesn't work!"). But of course it *is* valid, and *has been used repeatedly in print*.

Answer (score -1):

To start with, "its" can both be possessive pronoun(PP) as well as possessive adjective.(PA) " The kennel is its"(PP)...it belongs to ( the dog).  "It is its kennel(PA). In my opinion, I don't think the genitive " its" can and should be used as dummy. On the other hand, "it's" can. "It", IMO, which is a personal pronoun should never be confused with " its".

Comment: Nah. It's not idiomatically viable to say *The kennel is its*. You can only do that with *mine, yours, his, hers, ours, theirs*.

Comment: _It’s_ cannot be used as a dummy. Dummy _it_ can be fused with _is_ just like regular _it_, but the result is not a ‘dummy _it’s_’. And as FumbleFingers says, using _its_ as a pronoun is unusual at best; in your example here, I would call it downright ungrammatical. You can find cases where it’s at least borderline acceptable, like Iain Banks’ “Claiming the vengeance that was so surely its, exacting the price its enemies all deserved to pay” from _Algebraist_ (2005); but in general, it’s unidiomatic or ungrammatical.

Comment: Sorry but there is nothing IDIOMATIC about this. Plus, I don't see why THE KENNEL IS ITS should be wrong, except of course if you have a citation. If you can use MINE, YOURS, HERS, THEIRS, OURS and HIS like that, why on earth can't you use ITS.  Consider this, THE GOVERNMENT HAS A CHOICE TO MAKE...THE CHOICE IS ITS TO MAKE.  The puppy belongs to that dog...it is that dog's...it is its. Perfectly grammatical. Cheers.

Comment: Plus, it's can very much be used as a dummy. Who's knocking?... It's I...you can simply say I. . it's as dummy would sound like cleft. Thanks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’m afraid I must stand with the answerer on this one and demand a citation for your assertion that one cannot use *its* as a possessive pronoun the way one can *hers* and *theirs*. Here, in contrast, [is a citation for the contrary proposition](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/76339/2085) that one can indeed do that very thing; several citations, in point of fault. Elsewhere on this cite Lawler himself has said that this is completely possible, but as it was, of course, nestled in a comment, it is proving a challenge to search for.

Comment: @tchrist: As you say, OED gives just one citation for a usage I *personally* don't find acceptable as a "bare" noun. I'd happily accept ***its*** as a possessive determiner (or whatever you'd call ***its own***), but it wouldn't be a "dummy it" anyway, since in that *Henry VIII* context it clearly refers to ***the last [day]***...

Comment: ...which [interesting](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XWZZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA224&lpg=PA224&dq=%22Made+former+wonders+its%22&source=bl&ots=hOQ2IIGhHQ&sig=7ACSaZdyORMSngKFAdGCsTTfVh4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHg_qP0tLPAhVBCsAKHRWtALgQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=%22Made%20former%20wonders%20its%22&f=false) should apparently be ***the next day*** (I agree with the writer there who points out that this extended and somewhat tortured metaphor only makes sense if we swap ***next day*** and ***last day***).

Comment: @tchrist: [It may not have been nestled in a comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/76338/2303).